# insert many images which are in icollection in other model in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My first model

```
public class article
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string title { set; get; }
    public string bodyofarticle { set; get; }
    public ICollection <image> images { set; get; }
}
```

The second model which I use to store the images URL in the database

```
 public class image
    {
        public int id { set; get; }
        public int articleid { set; get; }
        public string url{ set; get; }
    }
```

Form to enter the values its okay to enter the 
article model but when I put any image it did not insert into the database

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>article</h4>
        <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.bodyofarticle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.bodyofarticle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" },   cols = 60, rows = 10 } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.bodyofarticle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <input type="file" multiple id="file" name="file" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

When I look at the break point I see that files are empty and I have tried many ways but it's still empty

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,title,bodyofarticle")] article    article , HttpPostedFileBase files)
 {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                      if (files != null && files.ContentLength >0 )
                      {
                        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
                        {
                            var v = Request.Files[file];

                              var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                              var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/"), fileName);
                              files.SaveAs(path);

                              image imag = new image();
                              imag.url = Url.Content("~/images/" + fileName);
                              article.images.Add(imag);
                          }

                      }
                    db.articles.Add(article);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(article);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the view. You will need to post the file from view.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", null, FormMethod.Post, new {  enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: also change the name of HttpPostedFileBase files to HttpPostedFileBase file.

Comment: there is also a problem in article.images.add(imag)

Comment: What is the error? kindly provide some information.

Comment: it's about migration 
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model backing the 'webdbc' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database 

i've updated the database by using "update-database -verbose" but it's still throwing this exception 
i'm really grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you used the command add-migrations before using the update-database command.

Answer (score 0):

//it was at the view

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", null, FormMethod.Post, new {  enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

//thnx vikrim and jim